# How to optimize API calls for a large dataset using Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, geometry, api, rest

**Objective**: Send a list of addresses to an API and extract certain information(eg: a flag which indicates if an address is in a flood zone or not).

**Solution**: Working Python script for small data.

**Problem**: I want to optimize my current solution for large input. How to improve the performance of the API calls. If I have 100,000 addresses will my current solution fail? Will this slow down the HTTP calls? Will I get a request TIME out? Does the API resist the number of API calls being made?

- Input: a list of addresses

*Sample input*

777 Brockton Avenue, Abington MA 2351

30 Memorial Drive, Avon MA 2322

- Output: A data frame of all addresses and a flag which indicates if it is in a flood zone or not.
- API: https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28/query.

My current solution works well for a small dataset.

```
# Creating a function to get lat & long of the existing adress and then detecting the zone in fema
def zonedetect(addrs):
    global geolocate
    geocode_result = geocode(address=addrs, as_featureset=True)
    latitude = geocode_result.features[0].geometry.x
    longitude = geocode_result.features[0].geometry.y
    url = "https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry="+str(latitude)+"%2C"+str(longitude)+"&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=json"
    response = req.get(url)
    parsed_data = json.loads(response.text)
    formatted_data = json_normalize(parsed_data["features"])
    formatted_data["Address_1"] = addrs

    #Exception handling
    if response.status_code == 200:
        geolocate = geolocate.append(formatted_data, ignore_index = True)
    else: 
        print("Request to {} failed".format(postcode))

# Reading every adress from existing dataframe
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    zonedetect(df["Address"][i])
```

Instead of using the for loop above is there an alternative. Can I process this logic in a batch?

Comment: Not an answer but an alternative; if it does not breach of API use, you can download whole map service. https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-6496-download-arcgis-online-feature-service-or-arcgis-server-featuremap-service